# How can I design a Custom ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am new to the `ActionBar`. I got the functionality but how do I design my own `actionbar` as in the image below:

[image]

> this my requirement:  How to design a custom actionbar. Does anyone know? Thanks to all

---

Comment: FYI, this is called ActionBar, not navigation bar!

Comment: ok how to desing myown actionbar like notificationcount and etc

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

you can use your own layout and apply with:

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

mActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: This is the correct way,you must be doing something wrong. check the layout and add this two lines: mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);